# Parse Nsmutabledictionary and extract value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Hello everyone i have one problem in parsing a dictionary here is dictionary

```
    {
    "@id" = 10;
    activityLocation = "";
    activityPriority = 1;
    actualEndDate = "<null>";
    actualStartDate = "<null>";
    children =         (
    );
    }
```

i am getting this responce in json and when i tried to parse this dictionay and tried to get the @id value from dictionary it gives me error like

```
[<__NSCFDictionary 0x7b07d370> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.
```

I have tried to get @id value like below code

```
NSString *id_user = [dictResponce valueForKey:@"@id"];
int user_id = [id_user intValue];
```

Please suggest me where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `valueForKey:` method for getting corresponding object from an NSDictionary, it should be `NSString *id_user = [dictResponce objectForKey:@"@id"];`.

For getting ann object with `valueForKey:`, it should be an `NSMutableDictionary`

**EDIT:**

Actual problem is not the `valueForKey:` method, The bug is in the key, you cannot use a leading `@` in a `valueForKey:` method, because `@` is used for collection operators like `@sum`, `@count` etc(its in `valueForKeyPath:` method, I don't know why its trowing exception in `valueForKey:` method also)
Ref:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 0):

You should use `objectForKey:` not `valueForKey:` -

```
NSNumber *id_user = [dictResponce objectForKey:@"@id"];
```

It looks like the id object is actually an `NSNumber` not an `NSString`, so I've also changed that.